# WireGuard config protection

Tags: vpn, wireguard, password-protected

I want to set up WireGuard in the corporate network instead of OpenVPN. How can the client's config be protected from theft or loss? If the client's config falls into the wrong hands, then attackers can use it

Comment: What's your threat scenario?

Comment: If a client is compromised, you remove the corresponding peer from the server configuration. Now that client will no longer be able to connect.

Comment: @larsks If there are more than 300 customers and one of the users leaves the wireguard config on the desktop in an Internet cafe and someone has connected with it, how can you then understand that the config is discredited?

Comment: In the question you talk about corporate network, in the comment about "customer" and "Internet cafe". Please, pick one. In the case of corporate network you can (and should) have a security policy in which the employee is responsible for the security of the VPN key they possess. Notice that this is equally applicable to WireGuard, OpenVPN or any other VPN solution.

Comment: This is a woefully inadequate VPN that allows an endpoint on an internal network with only one factor of authentication. Or even basic endpoint health checks. Or anything besides "we're dropping bad stuff on our heads and expect a technology solution for that".

Answer (score 1):

The `wg set wg0 private-key` command can get the private key from anywhere; it doesn't need to be a local file stored on disk. So for instance if you stored the private key as a GPG-encrypted file, you could do something like this:

```
wg set wg0 private-key <(gpg -d private.key.gpg)
```

This way the private key is always stored on disk encrypted; if the client device is compromised, the key remains protected.

[This article](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2023/02/wireguard-yubikey/) explores this solution in more detail as well as some variations on the theme involving password stores and yubikeys.

These solutions all mean that bringing up the VPN requires some sort of user interaction.